# Change python3 default folder permanently

Tags: centos, python

I have installed recently python3 (3.6.4) on my computer (CentOS 6). I can run it, program with it, and even managed to create a desktop shortcut, by putting "idle3" as a command (If I were to just put "idle", it would open python2). But the problems comes when I what to save the scripts, or when I want to open/save a file.

The python, for what it seems, it has the default directory `/home/Barlonium`. When I want to open/save a file, I have to change the directory manually, which is annoying.

I have looked for ways of changing the commands of the shortcut, by trying to change the current directory:

> cd /home/Barlonium/"Python Projects" && idle3

But I receive the following error:

> Details: Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)

I have tried to look for some document that contains the path or even how to change it permanently in the shell, but I can't find it on the net.

I want to change it permanently to `/home/Barlonium/Python Projects`. How can I do it?

P.S.: I'm not really sure if it in this section (unix.stackexchange), but on stackoverflow the Linux's tag clearly says that if it's not a linux-programming issue, this would be the appropriate site.

EDIT: Maybe it will help you helping me, but the shortcut seems to be an application of type `application/x-desktop`.

EDIT2: Resuming my problem, I don't know how to open python on a different saving folder. How can I do it, either permanently or with the shortcut commands (like I describe on the post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved over a discussion in the [Unix & Linux chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43078267#43078267).

The solution is to create a shortcut for the command

```
sh -c 'cd /home/Barlonium/"Python Projects" && exec idle3'
```

The shortcut itself can't be just `cd ... && idle3` because it does not know how to evaluate the `&&`.  The `sh` shell, on the other hand, knows how to do that.

The `exec` in front of `idle3` will replace the `sh` process with that of the `idle3` process.

---

[The Free Desktop standard](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) also says that you should be able to set the working directory using `Path="/home/Barlonium/Python Projects"` for the shortcut (I'm uncertain how it handles spaces and/or quotes), and have `Exec=idle3` (or possibly its full absolute path).

Comment: Might want to change that to `exec idle3` so that there isn't an unnecessary shell process floating around.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Agreed. I've added that.

Comment: I only wrote `sh -c 'cd $HOME/"Python Projects" && idle3'`

Comment: I mean, I only wrote that and worked. But I already added the `exec` command, as it was suggested.